# CZT resolution vs FFT resolution

Tags: fft

It is not clear to me if the CZT transform actually increases the resolution relative to the FFT or just does interpolation.
The resolution of the CZT transform is assumed to be arbitrary. Up to what limit?

Comment: The claim that one has higher resolution from the other can't hold, since the DFT is a special case of the CZT, so there's at least one case where resolution has to be the same. You will have to define what you consider to be the "resolution of the CZT transform", because as far as I can tell, *you* are the one to parameterize the base of the CZT you chose, and there's two free parameters.

Comment: Yes I understand that. The problem arises that supposedly the resolution that I can choose in the CZT is infinite, since I choose the resolution. My question is: What is the limit? There cannot be infinite resolution, it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I really don't understand how you come to the conclusion that you get infinite resolution. Then again, I don't know what you define as "resolution": Can you maybe extend on that?

Comment: The frequency resolution I am referring to is the difference in frequency between the different points of the signal spectrum after the CZT and FFT have been performed.
I attach some links to some articles that say that it improves the resolution of the frequency using CZT compared to FFT:
-https: //www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/816417
-https: //ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1433173

In these articles and others that I have read they say that the resolution in frequency in CZT only depends on the initial frequency and the final frequency that you choose in addition to the value of N.

Comment: That is, what I understand is that the value of the resolution in frequency in FFT is limited and in CZT I can observe the bandwidth that I choose without any type of limit.

Comment: if you don't insert a space between the https: and the rest of the URL, I could actually click on that...

Comment: So, the OSTI.gov article doesn't really address that resolution, and honestly, isn't that great. Anyways, as you can see in that article, the CZT doesn't have an "arbitrary" precision, you can control the distribution of the frequency bins. So, you can have some closer together than others, but you cannot gain "free resolution" without losing resolution somewhere else.

Comment: But what I understand is that you can 'zoom' in the area you want even if you lose resolution elsewhere. And you can then make another CZT of the same signal to get resolution elsewhere. That is, in the end you can zoom as much as you want and have infinite resolution in some way. For example, if I have a signal sampled with Fs = 10e12 and I want to see between f1 = 0.1e12 and f2 = 1e12, I zoom in on that area with CZT. Then I do another CZT on f1 = 0.5e12 f1 = 0.6e12 ... and so on infinitely until the frequency limit?